# Silverlight and reducing HTTP requests for images

Tags: silverlight, http, silverlight-4.0

I'm working on a project that has several Silverlight application islands spread through out our ASP.Net web application. We've decided to put all of our images in the ClientBin\SilverlightImages directory on the server and not to embed them in the XAP or the DLL. The images may be re-used and this would decrease the size of our XAPs, plus it's more of a lazy load of the images (which has its benefits). This has resulted in multiple http requests and sometimes blank areas until the image is loaded.

If you run the tool [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) from Yahoo, it mentions using image sprites to speed up your page loading. I want that same result for Silverlight. Is there a good approach to using image sprites as YSlow suggests in Silverlight? Or is there another approach, such as zipping similar files and then extracting it on the cilent? I'm also thinking about when the performance gains would start kicking in... 5 requests, 10, 20?

Comment: I'm still open for anymore suggestions on how this can be handled, but have accepted Keeano's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend loading the XNA Framework into your Silverlight application, now that it can support it.

That will have pre-set library's for SpriteSheets, essentially you could use a xml sheet and label each image and just load through them by ID and they would load instantly.
this is known as Spritesheets and is quit easy to learn and is implemented in any game you see to help with the amount of images to be rendered.

Comment: When you say "now that is can support it", do you mean Silverlight 4 or 5?

Comment: I do believe that would be 5, if you have done a system update on your PC it should be updated. http://www.uxmagic.com/blog/post/2011/04/21/e2809cXNA-for-Web-Browserse2809d-or-Silverlight-5-3D-from-Mix11.aspx that Link will be a good start for you and i really hope it helps, i would like to see more design patterns like this around being the fact that it holds a lot of design and feasibility.

Comment: I thought 5 was still in beta, but it looks like it is an RC now (exciting). I'll have to wait for the RTM, then convince people we need to update (at work), then see if I can work this out. Thanks for the link!

Comment: No problem, if this really did help please Vote it or choose it as an answer. Glad i could help :)

Comment: +1, I'm going to wait a few days to see if anyone else has some thoughts before checking it :-).